# How do i insert necessarily different values in 2 tables that have only one attribute and share the same foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

So i have a table 'category' that disjoints into 'simple_category' and 'super_category'. category has only one attribute which is its name. Same thing happens with the other 2 tables, which have a foreign key constraint to name. Super_category and simple_category cannot have the same name. How do i do that?

```
create table category(
    name varchar(20) not null,
    unique(name),
    primary key(name));

create table simple_category(
    name varchar(20),
    unique(name),
    primary key(name),
    foreign key(name) references categoria(name));

create table super_category(
    name varchar(20),
    unique(name),
    primary key(name),
    foreign key(name) references categoria(name));
```

I expect an error message when i try to insert equal values into super_category and simple_category

Comment: (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Search re disjoin subtypes. There are declarative enforcement idioms that stores type tags in supertype & sometimes subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one method is a trigger.  Another method is to put the type into the category table and include it in the foreign key relationships:

```
create table category (
    category_id serial primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    type varchar(20) not null,
    check type in ('super', 'simple'),
    unique (name),
    unique (type, name)  -- redundant but needed for foreign key reference
);

create table simple_category (
    category_id serial primary key,
    type varchar(20) default 'simple',
    foreign key (type, category_id) references categoria (type, category_id)
);

create table super_category (
    category_id serial primary key,
    type varchar(20) default 'super',
    foreign key (type, category_id) references categoria (type, category_id)
);
```

Note that I also modified the tables to have auto-incrementing primary keys, so names are not repeated everywhere.

How does this work?  First insert the category into `categoria` with the appropriate type.  Then insert the reference in the appropriate table.  You could do the second using a trigger.  However, I am guessing that there is other information you want, which is why they are split into different tables.

Answer (score 0):

That would be constraint triggers checking for the existence of the name in the other table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION tf_simple_category_biu ()
                RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM super_category sc
                    WHERE sc.name = new.name) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'Duplicate names are not allowed.';
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER simple_category_biu
                          AFTER INSERT
                                 OR UPDATE
                                    OF name
                          ON simple_category
                          FOR EACH ROW
                          EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf_simple_category_biu();

CREATE FUNCTION tf_super_category_biu ()
                RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM simple_category sc
                    WHERE sc.name = new.name) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'Duplicate names are not allowed.';
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER super_category_biu
                          AFTER INSERT
                                 OR UPDATE
                                    OF name
                          ON super_category
                          FOR EACH ROW
                          EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf_super_category_biu();
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=0499d97d4b7b7458036284f329118fbf)